# Log4J2 (2.6) - Delete logs automatically

Tags: java, logging, properties, log4j, log4j2

I'm currently trying to get the Delete Action running in the new Log4j2 (2.6).
There is the possibility to delete log files, with preconfigured conditions, like file size or age.
The information about that is really rare on the web, but enough to configure it someway.
Anyway, it's not working for me.

We are using a properties file to configure our Log4J2.
The writing works absolutely as expected, only the deletion doesn't.

So, here's a snippet of our properties file:

## main log file

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile

appender.rolling.name = RollingFile

appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}

appender.rolling.filePattern = log/%d{yyyyMMdd}_xxxlog.zip

appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout

appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2m

appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true

appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy

appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete

appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = /log

appender.rolling.strategy.action.maxdepth = 1

appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfLastModified

appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.age = 1D

appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.type = IfFileName

appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.glob = *.log

All starts with the line: **appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete**
```

Next there comes the basepath. Here I tried multiple options, like an absolute path or relative path.
I also tried it with and without starting and ending slashes... some of that tries leads to an error in the console, so at least "/log" seems to be the correct way (also you can use /log/).

On the third line, "appender.rolling.strategy.action.maxdepth = 1" I tried experiemented with some more values. Just to be sure, that this is not the problem. All logfiles are in the root directory, so 1 seems to be correct.

Next line: **appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfLastModified**

I just looked in the code, after it wasn't working as expected, just to be absolute sure, there is a function IfLastModified. It is all there, and in the console I can confirm, its called and "working".

Next: **appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.age = 1D**
Here I tried multiple options as well. 1 m , 1 D... and to be sure, I copied old logfiles in the directory, which are older than 1 minute and / or older than 1 day.

**appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.type = IfFileName**

Here's the condition, which files you want to delete. I started with *.log
but I also tried an absolute name logfile.log and many other possibilities. I have .zip, .log, .txt...

Then I come over the possiblity, that the software may not have the rights to delete something in that folder. I gave the files permission and access to all things, just like write, read, delete.
After all, I'm able to say, that the properties configuration seems to be fine, because there no errors.
But it's just not working.

Ah, last but not least, I also figured out that blank spaces at the end of a line cause errors.
There are no blank spaces... that's not the problem at all.

Has anybody an idea why it is not working?
I appreciate any help or idea.
Thank you very much.

Have a nice day,

Timm

Comment: `<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>` is something you're probably looking out for?

Comment: Configuring internal Log4j2 status logging to TRACE may be useful. That will show details of what happens during a rollover to the console.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. 
I already configured it to trace. That shows me at first some config errors, when I configured some wrong value, e.g. :

appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.age = 1 (notice theres no valid specification like month, day). That gets logged. If I configure it with, the failure disappears. And this is why I came to the conclusion, its configured right. There must be something other I oversee.

Comment: @nullpointer: What do you mean?
I see its a bit of xml-config, right?
I found that: 
 
Try adding the default Rollover strategy ` <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>` that will allow only 3 files per day, use whatever number you want.

But thats not what I'm öooking for. Actually I would be very happy if it clears all or one log file, but nothing happens. No trace, no error, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured `RollingFileAppender` similar to yours configuration. I think 2 points which you should modify in your properties to make it working -

```
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1

appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.glob = *.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The following configs works for me.

```
appender.rolling.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type=Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath=${sys:log.dir}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth=1
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifFileName.type=IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifFileName.glob=audit-*.log.gz
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type=IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age=30d
```